# How to determine if a function is empty

Tags: javascript, reflection

I want to be able to check whether a given function is empty or not. That is, there is nothing in its body, eg:

```
function foo() {}
function iAmEmpty(a) {
    // yep, empty
}
```

With some initial playing around, I've got something which I think might be ok, by using `toString()` and some regexes.

```
function foo(a, b, c) {}

/^function[^{]+\{\s*\}/m.test(foo.toString());  // true

function bar(a, b, c) { var d; }

/^function[^{]+\{\s*\}/m.test(bar.toString());  // false
```

I was just wondering if there was a better approach? Are there any problems with the above you can see?

Comment: The concept of JS reflection made me lol, but as to the problem; you've dealt with whitespace and multiline, so afaik this is as good as it gets.

Comment: Don't forget to look for method bodies that are all comments (if that's your spec)

Comment: I think it is a good approach to do like that.

Comment: @Brad, comments are automatically removed from the output of toString(), AFAIK.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960335/javascript-is-given-function-empty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript : is given function empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960335/javascript-is-given-function-empty)

Answer (score 14):

This isn't advisable. There is no standard determining precisely what a function's `toString()` method should return, so even if you get this working in current browsers, future browsers may justifiably change their implementation and break your code.

Kangax has written briefly about this: http://perfectionkills.com/those-tricky-functions/

Comment: Thanks for the link! I didn't realise the differences in browser implementations were so extreme.

Comment: @Tim 

ES5: [Function.prototype.toString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.2)

ES6 [Function.prototype.toString](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.prototype.tostring)

Comment: @ManasJayanth: The key word is "precisely". Both specs say that an "implementation-dependent representation" of the function is returned.

Comment: Oh right. My bad :) But running a couple of simple function `toStrings` s seem to return consistent results on Mac across browsers (FF, Safari and Chrome), non native functions that is.

Answer (score 8):

## Arrow functions...

As I am sure you are aware, `javascript` supports [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which are really succinct but unfortunately don't work with your neat `regex`.

I quickly converted your nice `regex` into its own `function` which takes a `function` as an input and returns whether or not it is empty for simplicity later. Just to demonstrate how arrow functions can be widely used, I put it in one:

```
isEmpty = f => /^function[^{]+\{\s*\}/m.test(f.toString())
```

Now, we can easily test an empty function:

```
function eF() {}
```

which as we would expect with `isEmpty(eF)` returns `true`.

And once more with an actual function:

```
function retOne() {return 1;}
```

which again as expected with `isEmpty(retOne)` returns `false`.

However, the issue I encountered was with arrow functions so to initialize an empty one again, we have a shorter syntax of the original:

```
eF = () => {}
```

and the `'stringified'`version of that is quite different to the one before:

```
"() => {}"
```

so of course in this case the call `isEmpty(eF)` returns `false` when we want `true`. I'm not sure if you require to test if all functions (i.e. including `arrow functions`) are empty but if you do, your  `regex`will need modifying...

I am not great at writing them myself, but have attempted a couple and one further thing that you might want to consider is the lenient nature of the `arrow functions` especially this part of the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements }
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
// equivalent to: (param1, param2, …, paramN) => { return expression; }

// Parentheses are optional when there's only one parameter name:
(singleParam) => { statements }
singleParam => { statements }
```

which shows how the curly brackets `{...}` are not always necessary. So this function:

```
retOne = () => 1
```

is `valid` and could make forming a new `regex` more difficult. One workaround I thought of is to just remove all curly brackets from `f.toString()` using:

`str.replace(/[{}]/g, '')`.

and then work with a `regex test` from there.

Hopefully this is something helpful to consider if you want `arrow functions` to also be able to be tested.

Answer (score 4):

The best thing you can try, to fit the maximum possibilities (as this is pretty hard to achieve), is to add [acorn](https://github.com/ternjs/acorn) or [esprima](http://esprima.org/) (**works with arrow functions too**) libraries and process the JavaScript function. It will tokenize it for you to parse, so you can process it to your likings, checking if there's actually zero code inside, or there's only variable declarations without any calculation nor return, etc...

Is pretty straightforward to implement:

```js
function check(f) {
  console.log("");
  console.log("Checking", f);
  var syntax = esprima.parse(f);
  if (syntax.body.length != 1) {
    console.log("Weird process");
  } else {
    function processBody(body) {
      if (!body || body.length == 0) {
        console.log("Body seems empty. YAY!");
      } else {
        for (var i = 0, command; command = body[i]; i++) {
          if (command.type != "VariableDeclaration") {
            console.log("Body has a", command.type, ", so is not empty.");
            return;
          }
        }
        console.log("Body has only variable declarations, so is empty! (or not, whatever fit your needs)");
      }
    }
    function process(dec) {
      if (dec.type != "FunctionDeclaration") {
        console.log("Weird declaration");
      } else {
        console.log("Function", dec.id.name, "has", dec.params.length, "params");
        processBody(dec.body.body);
      }
    }
    process(syntax.body[0]);
  }
}

check("function hasReturn(arg1, arg2) {var a = arg1 + arg2;return a;}");
check("function hasArgumentsButNoBody(arg1, arg2) {}");
check("function isCompletelyEmptyWithSpacesAndTabsAndLinefeeds() {   \t    \t   \r\n \r\n  }");
check("function hasOnlyVariables() {var a, b = 2; var c = 1 + b;}");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/esprima/2.7.3/esprima.min.js"></script>
```

This will not run the functions, just parse them, so is safe to run with non-secure functions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the use for this, but you could make it simpler by anchoring the pattern to the **end** of the string.

```
  /[^{\s]\s*\}$/.test(String(bar))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Function.prototype.hasBody = function() {
    return !/{\s*}$/.test(this.toString());
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple just check the function contain and then check the contain if it's empty or not  .
check this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/eT7yUD7sYx1VLmW9O9yL?p=info)
here's full working code:

```
function foo(a, b, c) {}

function bar(a, b, c) {
  var d;
}

function isEmpty(value) {
  return (value == null || value.length === 0);
}

function check(test) {
  var entire = test.toString();
  var body = entire.slice(entire.indexOf("{") + 1, entire.lastIndexOf("}"));
  return body;

}
console.log(isEmpty(check(foo)), isEmpty(check(bar))); //return true false
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the function overrides the toString method.

Comment: @AlexisTyler check the plunker

Comment: @AlexisTyler there's mention about overriding in your question anyways you can save the default toString function inside an other function if you aim to override it