# Javascript : is given function empty?

Tags: javascript

Let's have a function call

```
function doSomethingAndInvokeCallback(callback){
    // do something
    callback();
}
```

I can check if given argument is function `if(typeof callback == 'function')`

How can I discover, if given callback function is function and isn't empty?

like

```
doSomethingAndInvokeCallback(function(){
    //nothing here
})
```

Comment: It's nevertheless an interesting problem.

Comment: What about `function some_name(a,b,c,d,e) { 42; }`? That function has no effect whatsoever, but is not "empty".

Comment: I feel rather than debating the efficacy of this question, we should be trying to answer it as if it's pure Mathematics.  Pointless, but interesting.

Comment: Hmm sounds like really interesting.

Comment: @kay yes, this is problem, and if we could find solution to this type of functions doing just nothing, this would be great

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368137/how-to-get-javascript-functions-source-code-from-specific-site-using-firebug

Comment: Apart from longer and uglier regexps I guess there is no way of checking what a function actually does without executing it. Even if you do execute it, you can't always know whether it will change local variables etc.

Comment: @pimvdb Or you can use acorn or esprima.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no totally reliable way to know if a function is empty because there are multiple kinds of functions in JS, some implemented with JS and some implemented with native code and you can't know for sure whether the function passed in does anything or not.  If you want to limit the passed in function to only very simple JS functions, you could use the mechanisms outlined by other answers here (examining the source of the function).  But, I would not recommend doing that in anything but a tightly controlled situation because there are lots of legal javascript ways to break that.

I would suggest that you should change the contract of your function arguments and have the caller pass null or not pass anything (which will make the argument `undefined`) rather than an empty function.  Then, it will be very clear whether they intend to have a function called or not.  If they then pass an empty function instead of null or undefined, they are getting the behavior that the interface of the function specifies.  The caller can choose the desired behavior and you can implement your function in a more failsafe manner.

Also, one of your main suppositions in your question is not quite right.  You cannot safely use `typeof x == "function"` to determine if something is a function as that will not work reliably in some older versions of IE for some types of functions.  If you want to learn how to detect if something is a function at all, you can learn from jQuery here (even if you're not using it).  jQuery has a function it uses internally all the time called `jQuery.isFunction()` that returns a bool.  It uses that mostly for testing arguments to see if a function was passed.

Internally, it calls:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(o)
```

and then examines the result.  If the result has "Function" in it, then test test parameter is a function.

So, using the same technique used in jQuery, you could build your own simple little `isFunction` routine like this:

```
function isFunction(test) {
    return(Object.prototype.toString.call(test).indexOf("Function") > -1);
}
```

Of course, if you have jQuery available, you could just use it's own version:

```
jQuery.isFunction(o)
```

When there are questions with potential cross browser compatibility issues, I find it instructional to look at how one of the big libraries solves the issue, even if you aren't going to be using that library.  You can be sure that the libraries have been vetted against many browsers so a technique they are using is safe.  You sometimes have to unwrap all their own internal routines they may use to figure out what they're really doing (which was the case for this function), but you can save yourself a lot of legwork.

You can see a working test bed for this here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/PKcsM/

In modern browsers `typeof fn === "function"`, but in older versions of IE, some functions give a `typeof === "object"` which is probably why jQuery uses this other method which does work in those older versions of IE.

Comment: I like this answer the most of all, as a most descriptive. Thanks

Comment: +1 But even in IE7, `Object.prototype.toString.call(alert) === "[object Object]"` so it's still not fully reliable.

Comment: @primvdb - You're right about IE7.  Even jQuery gets that one wrong.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that you can define a function to retrieve the body of a function([1](http://www.jslab.dk/library/Function.getBody)). I wrote a small (non-definitive) test of this:

http://jsfiddle.net/6qn5P/

```
Function.prototype.getBody =
  function() {
    // Get content between first { and last }
    var m = this.toString().match(/\{([\s\S]*)\}/m)[1];
    // Strip comments
    return m.replace(/^\s*\/\/.*$/mg,'');
  };

function foo() {
    var a = 1, b = "bar";
    alert(b + a);
    return null;
}

console.log(foo.getBody());
console.log(foo.getBody().length);
```

Comment: This is actually the right answer. I needed something like this to check whether a jQuery plugin callback was the default one I defined, or a custom one defined by the Plugin user. This function made it happen. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that solutions that rely on extending prototypes of base elements like functions should be regarded as correct. This is ONE solution, but extending the function prototype should always be the last resort.

Comment: Agreed. This answer was meant to show a possibility. That's why it has the term "non-definitive" in it :)

Answer (score 5):

One possibility is matching the `.toString` result against a regexp to get the function body, and then trim to check whether it has become an empty string:

```
var f = function foo()    { 


};

/^function [^(]*\(\)[ ]*{(.*)}$/.exec(
     f.toString().replace(/\n/g, "")
)[1].trim() === ""; // true
```

That ugly regexp does take care of spaces aroung named functions as well as extraneous spaces before the name and the opening brace. Spaces like in `foo  ()` do seem to be removed, so there is no reason to check for those.

Answer (score 3):

You *might* be able to get this from `.toString()`:

```
var blank = function(){};
var f = function(){};
var f2 = function() { return 1; };

f.toString() == blank.toString(); // true
f2.toString() == blank.toString(); // false
```

but this is *really* prone to error:

```
var blank = function(){};
var f = function(){ }; // extra space!
f.toString() == blank.toString(); // false
```

You could munge the strings a bit to try to overcome this, but I suspect this is very browser-dependent. I wouldn't actually try to do this in a production environment if I were you. Even if you normalize the whitespace, it still won't catch other no-op lines, including comments, useless `var` statements, etc. To actually address these issues, you'd probably need a whole tokenizer system (or a crazy regex).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it for a host function, but for others, you can fairly reliably do

```
function isEmpty(f) {
  return typeof f === "function" &&
      /^function[^{]*[{]\s*[}]\s*$/.test(
          Function.prototype.toString.call(f));
}
```

This isn't efficient, but major interpreters implement `toString` for functions in such a way that it works, though it will not work on some interpreters for some empty-ish functions

```
function () { /* nothing here */ }
function () { ; }
function () { return; }
```

Answer (score 1):

In some implementation you can just do a toString() on the function and get it's content. Though it contains comments etcetera.

```
var foo = function(){ /* Comment */ };
alert(foo.toString());
```

Comment: Checked on `NodeJS v0.10.28` and Google Chrome Browser. Got the output as `'function (){ /* Comment */ }'`. I think, this is not working on those.