# Why does prototyping Function not affect console.log?

Tags: javascript, console, prototyping

I prototyped `Function` so that it has a getBody function:

```
Function.prototype.getBody = function() {
    // Get content between first { and last }
    var m = this.toString().match(/\{([\s\S]*)\}/m)[1];
    // Strip comments
    return m.replace(/^\s*\/\/.*$/mg,'');
};
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7960435/1643670) for more info.
I tried to test it this way:

```
console.log(console.log.getBody.getBody());
```

but received an error: `TypeError: console.log.getBody is undefined`.
I figured out that maybe this happens because `console.log` was defined before I actually prototyped `Function` so I created an empty function `x` right before the prototyping and tried to call

```
console.log(x.getBody.getBody());
```

which worked without a problem. Checking the type of `console.log` with `typeof console.log` results in "function". Here's a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/maHsE) to try it out. All of this wasn't really a surprise since it's what I expected except of `console.log.getBody` to be undefined.

So why does prototyping `Function` not affect `console.log`? I'm using Firefox 18.0.1 with Firebug 1.11.1.

Comment: Works fine for me (IE10)

Comment: This works fine for me in Chrome 24.

Comment: Thanks, I added browser + version to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with Firebug not with Firefox per se. My guess is that `Function` in Firebug lives in a different scope then `Function` in your page. (since unlike the other browsers Firebug is an extension , not a built in browser tool)

In fact if instead of Firebug you use the built in Firefox console ([Ctrl+Shift+K](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console#Opening_the_Web_Console)), your code works perfectly fine.

More information about Firebug internals can be found here

http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_Internals

This excerpt may be interesting

> When Firebug is detached from Firefox, open in a new or separate
>   window, the new window has its own scope. In that scope, a few Firebug
>   script tags compile to create a connection back to the original
>   browser.xul window. Most important, chrome.js is unique to each top
>   level window, but the Firebug object used by the detached window is
>   the object of the parent browser.xul.

Comment: As if I needed more proof of Firefox being a stupid browser :D

Comment: The issue is in Firebug, not Firefox. :)

Comment: Thanks, I think I might get it now. I still don't fully understand firebugs implementation of `console.log`: `function () { return Function.apply.call(x.log, x, arguments); }` but thats a different question.