# Function.apply vs. Function.prototype.apply

Tags: javascript, function, apply

I recently looked into the code of firebugs `console.log` by calling `console.log.toString()` and got this:

```
function () { return Function.apply.call(x.log, x, arguments); }
```

As long as I understand this causes `Function.apply` to be called with its `this` referring to `x.log` and the arguments being `x` and `arguments`. Since `Function.apply` itself calls functions this will result in `x.log` to be called with its `this` referring to `x` and `arguments` as its arguments.

Which leads me to my question: Is there any reason to call `Function.apply` this way instead of just using `Function.prototype.apply`? Or in other words, is there any difference between the above and `return x.log.apply(x, arguments)`?

**Edit:** Since it's open source I took a quick look at the firebug sourcecode and found the place where this is created ([consoleInjector.js](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/master/extension/content/firebug/console/consoleInjector.js), line 73):

```
// Construct a script string that defines a function. This function returns
// an object that wraps every 'console' method. This function will be evaluated
// in a window content sandbox and return a wrapper for the 'console' object.
// Note that this wrapper appends an additional frame that shouldn't be displayed
// to the user.
var expr = "(function(x) { return {\n";
for (var p in console)
{
    var func = console[p];
    if (typeof(func) == "function")
    {
        expr += p + ": function() { return Function.apply.call(x." + p +
            ", x, arguments); },\n";
    }
}
expr += "};})";

// Evaluate the function in the window sandbox/scope and execute. The return value
// is a wrapper for the 'console' object.
var sandbox = Cu.Sandbox(win);
var getConsoleWrapper = Cu.evalInSandbox(expr, sandbox);
win.wrappedJSObject.console = getConsoleWrapper(console);
```

I'm almost sure now that this has something to do with `Function` to be in a different scope, which is what I sayed in my first comment to **pst**'s answer, but I still don't fully understand it. I may do a bit further research about that.

Comment: I'm curious as to why the code is not just using the result of `Cu.evalInSandbox("Function", sandbox)` in a standard closure approach (as the function-objects are apparently returned), but apparently there is a reason .. actually, that doesn't make much since either, since `Function` should *not* be closed over; unless there be more magic in `evalInSandbox` ..

Answer (score 6):

Consider this:

```
Function.hasOwnProperty("apply")             // false
Function.apply == Function.prototype.apply   // true
Function.__proto__ == Function.prototype     // true in FF which exposes proto
```

So Function.apply works because Function's [[prototype]] is [Function.prototype](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4). In this case both ought to work as desired.

However, consider that normal [[GetProperty]](http://es5.github.com/#x8.12.2) rules still apply:

```
var f = function () {};
f.apply = "nubbits";
f.apply(/* err */);
```

Granted, I'd consider it "questionable code" to change the behavior of `apply` (and especially in an incompatible manner), but it's *possible* that the two forms differ .. Personally, I do *not* accommodate such hypothetical situations and I use `f.apply` in my code.

Comment: I've wondered this - then why would it be "better" to use `Function.prototype.apply` over `myFunc.apply` (the OP's other question)?

Comment: @Ian Perhaps one prefers the "explicit form". I can't think of a distinguishing reason that I have run into in my code - me, I prefer `fn.apply`. (And if someone changes what it does, then that's on them ..)

Comment: So this would be only done to stop one of altering the behaviour of `console.log.apply`? Hard to think of this to be the only reason... I'm also thinkin that this could be done because of `Function` (the one on which `apply` is called) to be in another scope, which most likely was the issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715140/why-does-prototyping-function-not-affect-console-log

Comment: @YingYang Well, one can alter `Function.prototype.apply` if they really desire. The difference with the latter is someone might make a "really special function object" without explicitly altering the prototype .. personally I would *not* write code accommodating of this; if the code did not make the custom apply compatible, then someone else broke it - not me. There are assumptions that must be made, and this is one I would hold to. The latter example was just to show that normal own-properties-shadow-prototype rules still apply. I prefer/use `fn.apply`.

Comment: I agree with you, I also wouldn't do that. Which is why I find it hard to believe that this should be the only reason. Aditionally, if you wan't to prevent someone to alter the functionality of `apply` shouldn't you also think about preventing someone from altering the functionality of `call` then? `Function.apply.call` wouldn't be very usefull in this case. I edited my question to contain firebugs original source code with the comments and I'm almost sure that this has to do with different scopes now. Yours is still a pretty good answer which is why i upvoted it.