# Using a Function.prototype for the console.log function

Tags: javascript, prototype

I created a prototype-function like this, and it works fine for "normal" functions:

```
Function.prototype.my = function() {
...
}
```

but when I invoke it from the console.log function I get the error:
*console.log.my is not a function*.

I am using Firefox 38.0.1 on Mac 10.8.5.
Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/okrw6ae4/

**It only occurs in the Firebug (2.0.10) console.** With the built in console it works.

any ideas?

Comment: It works fine in Chrome

Comment: What browser/environment is this not working in?

Comment: Consider reproducing the problem.

Comment: Extending build-in JavaScript objects is bad practice. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: calling `Function.my()` looks good to me

Comment: This question has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715140/why-does-prototyping-function-not-affect-console-log